# Polymorphic association inserts 0 instead of raising error when column is misconfigured as Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's one that stumped me for a while, though in retrospect it should have been obvious. I was getting the error message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for 0:Fixnum
```

when accessing a model through a polymorphic association. Turns out the table on the `belongs_to` side of the association had an integer `type` column instead of a string.

Easily fixed, but it seems like Rails ought to raise an error in this situation -- instead it happily adds the row with 0 in the type column.

Comment: i think type is mysql reserved keyword please change your column name and try again.

Comment: The column isn't named `type` -- it's `something_type`, where `something` is the name of the polymorphic association.

Comment: I think the answer to this is 'set up your columns properly rather than blame rails'

Comment: I'm glad you had this problem (but not in a malicious way) because I've just been climbing up the walls trying to solve exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. I feel kinda dumb for putting the type as and integer instead of a string and not realizing though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because parameters sent through with requests come through as strings, and therefore for integer columns that are set from params, rails calls to_i on the string to get the integer.  If it can't resolve an integer from it (which happens if the string doesn't start with some digits) then to_i returns 0.  This is just how ruby works.  Sometimes rails will spot this and raise a warning, but it can't possibly know the name of every column that it has to check.  Eg check this out (from console)

```
>> quiz = Quiz.first
=> <a quiz>
>> quiz.user_id = "foo"
=> "foo"
>> quiz.save
=> true
>> quiz.user_id
=> 0
```

Comment: You're right of course -- set the columns up correctly in the first place, and there's no problem. But in this case, I think Rails could spot the polymorphic association (based on the column names) and give a warning when running migrations. Sure would have saved me some hair-pulling.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `modeltable_type` was was not a `string type` fixing this solve my problem.